# Google app engine - local development server timezone

Tags: google-app-engine

I understood from the GAE documentation that the production server timezone is always UTC. While developing locally, the server timezone is set to CET. Is there a way to force the local development server to also run on UTC ?

The development server is running on Mac OS.

Thanks,

Hugues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jut found the answer. In order to set the server timezone, just go in Eclipse, "Run configurations", then "VM arguments" and add the following "-Duser.timezone=UTC".

This will set the server timezone to the value you want (UTC) in this case. This is really handy as Google App Engine production will always run UTC whereas the development server (at least in my case) was running with local timezone. The net effect was that I had a different behavior between dev and prod.

Hugues

Comment: Please file a bug -- this is an unintended difference between dev and prod environment.

Comment: yes, I thought it was unintended as I've always found the DEV server treatment of TZ's has been flakey.  Recent versions of GAE (1.7.3 for example) seem to always use local TZ, whereas before it used to use UTC unless you hit the server 'restart' button.  So I was always forced to stop and restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use this while saving a date value to your datastore to convert to your specific timezone.

```
    DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(patternString);
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat indianFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(patternString);
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    Date timestamp = utcFormat.parse(inputString);
    String output = indianFormat.format(timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur. You are right, this will change the timezone but only for the current query I was looking for a way to change the setting as a global setting from the server side. Just found the answer (see below). Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

GAE devServer uses local Timezone by default.

I use this code to force it to UTC:

```
boolean isDevEnvironment = SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development;

    if (isDevEnvironment) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC.toTimeZone());
        DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    }
```

You need to run it once, in the very during server startup and initialization.

Comment: My GAE devServer in Ubuntu is not using local Timezone.  It's using UTC by default.  My system's local time is definitely set correctly.